# lodash pick behaves differently when imported using es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I found `pick` imported like this in a React project and decided to test how it works:

```
import { pick } from 'lodash/fp';

let obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };

let result = pick(obj, ['a', 'c']);
console.log(result); // => {}
```

Then tested it using require and got the expected output.

```
const _ = require('lodash')

let object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };

let result = _.pick(object, ['a', 'c']);
console.log(result); // => { 'a': 1, 'c': 3 }
```

**Why doesn't it work in the same way in both cases?**

Comment: In the one case, you're loading it from `lodash/fp`; in the other case, you're loading it from `lodash`. Are those the same thing?

Comment: I was expecting them to be the same. I didn't think lodash can have 2 picks.

Comment: lodash and lodash/fp are not the same; [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) is an FP spin on lodash. (I don't know if that explains the difference, just flagging it up.)

Comment: I understand now.  Thank you for clearing.Big breakthrough here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the import. In your first example, you're using [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide), not lodash. In your second example, you're using lodash.

If you want `pick` from lodash:

```
import { pick } from 'lodash';
```

---

Proof: If we use old-style `require` on both, we still get different results:

```
var pick1 = require('lodash/fp').pick;
var pick2 = require('lodash').pick;

var obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };

var result = pick1(obj, ['a', 'c']);
console.log(result); // => {}

result = pick2(obj, ['a', 'c']);
console.log(result); // => {a: 1, c: 3}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the way you imported is wrong. Import it like this

```
import pick from 'lodash/pick';
```